# css animation gets hanged while script load

Tags: jquery, css, animation, css-animations, getscript

I am using jquery's `$.getScript` block to cache javascript files.

Here is the code using `$.when`

```
function loadResources() {
    $.ajaxSetup({
        cache:true
    });
    $("#animate").removeClass("hideBlock");

    $.when(
        $.getScript( "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js" ),
        $.getScript( "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js" ),
        $.getScript( "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.0/dojo/dojo.js" ),
        $.getScript( "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/ext-core/3.1.0/ext-core.js" ),
        $.getScript( "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.3/jquery.mobile.min.js" ),
        $.getScript( "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js" ),
        $.getScript( "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/mootools/1.5.1/mootools-yui-compressed.js" ),
        $.getScript( "http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2013.1.319/js/kendo.all.min.js" ),
        $.getScript( "http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2013.1.319/js/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js" ),
        $.getScript( "http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.2.903/js/kendo.all.min.js" ),
        $.getScript( "http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.2.903/js/kendo.all.min.js" ),
        $.getScript( "http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/content/shared/js/kendo-dojo.js" ),
        $.getScript( "http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/content/shared/js/console.js" ),
        $.getScript( "http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/content/shared/js/prettify.js" ),
        $.getScript( "http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/content/shared/inspector/inspector.js" ),
        $.Deferred(function( deferred ){
            $( deferred.resolve );
        })
    ).done(function(){
        $("#animate").addClass("hideBlock");
        $.ajaxSetup({
            cache:false
        });
    });
}
```

HTML:

```
<a id="trigger" href="javascript:void(0)">Click to load</a>
<div id="animate" class="hideBlock"></div>
```

In my html I have used css3 animation. This animation should be displayed as long as the scripts are getting loaded.

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/nL1ubLyt/3/

When the script is loaded using `$.getScript` then the loading animation gets hanged in Firefox. In chrome is works fine. I don't think it is a problem with $.getScript. But any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you need to turn on async : true , something like bellow

```
$.ajaxSetup({async: true});
```